# Add RoutedEvent via TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, border, routed-events, templatebinding

I want to use a `RoutedEvent` on a `Border` in a XAML Dictionary. The `RoutedEvent` comes from the class for which the template is, how can I achieve this?

ModernWindow.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets fired when the logo is clicked.
/// </summary>
public static readonly RoutedEvent LogoClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("LogoClickRoutedEventHandler", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ModernWindow));

/// <summary>
/// The routedeventhandler for LogoClick
/// </summary>
public event RoutedEventHandler LogoClick 
{
    add { AddHandler(LogoClickEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(LogoClickEvent, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
protected virtual void OnLogoClick() 
{
    RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(LogoClickEvent, this));
}
```

ModernWindow.xaml

```
<!-- logo -->
<Border MouseLeftButtonDown="{TemplateBinding LogoClick}" Background="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="36" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,76,0">
    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Logo}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found finally a solution, I used `InputBindings` and then `Commands`.

```
<Border.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="presentation:Commands.LogoClickCommand" Gesture="LeftClick" />
</Border.InputBindings>
```

Its not that what I wanted, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

I think in your situation, you can use `EventSetter`, it is just designed to do this. For you it would look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type SomeControl}">
    <EventSetter Event="Border.MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="LogoClick" />
    ...

</Style>
```

**`Note:`** `EvenSetter` can not be set via triggers and cannot be used in a style that is contained in a theme resource dictionary, so usually it is put at the beginning of the current style.

For more information, see:

[EventSetter Class in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx)

Or if you necessary to use it in a `ResourceDictionary`, you can do it differently. Create the `DependencyProperty` (can also be attached). Example with attached `DependencyProperty`:

Property definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleProperty =
                                          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Sample",
                                          typeof(bool),
                                          typeof(SampleClass),
                                          new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSample));

private static void OnSample(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

If you try to set the value of our property, called `On Sample`, in which you'll be able to do what you need (almost as well as event).

Set the value for the property, depending on the event, you might like:

```
<EventTrigger SourceName="MyBorder" RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:SampleClass.Sample)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Thx, but exactly this is the problem, I need it in a Theme Dictionary for a Custom User Control...

Comment: @Knerd: See in the answer about the dependency property.